# why this piece of code prints only 1 and not the entire elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, c

I simply declared a 1D array along with a pointer that is pointing to the whole array. I then implemented a for loop expecting to print all the elements in my array. But the for loop is printing only 1. I need to know why it is not printing all the elements of the particular array.Here's is the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}, (*pointer)[5] = &array;
  for(*pointer; *pointer <= (array + 4); *pointer++) {
    printf("%d", **pointer);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect pointer to point to after incrementing it?

Comment: I expect the pointer to point to the next element address.

Comment: @ShreyashWankhede Then simply use `int *pointer = array` then loop through it.

Answer (score 4):

`pointer` is a pointer to an `int[5]` array. Incrementing it by one moves it past the entirety of `array` in one fell swoop (it's equivalent to adding `5` to an `int*`), while `array + 4` (which resolves `array` to a pointer to `int`), only adds four `int`s to it, not four `int[5]`'s worth of space, so you only print the first element, then the loop terminates (`array + 4` is one `int` *before* `pointer + 1`'s address).

If you want `pointer` to point to just one element, don't declare it with `(*pointer)[5]`, use plain `int*`s; there's little benefit to making it a pointer to array here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a pointer to print an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    const int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    
    int *pointer;
    for(pointer = array; pointer < array + size; pointer++)
        printf("%d ", *pointer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember - when you increment a pointer, it gets incremented in steps of the *object size* that the pointer can point to.

The type of `pointer` is `int (*)[5]` i.e. pointer to an array of `5` integers, which means, `pointer` can point to any array of type `int [5]`. This expression `*pointer++` in `for` loop will be grouped as -  `*(pointer++)` [check [operator precedence table]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) i.e. the `pointer` will be first incremented by size of object of type `int [5]` and then the unary `*` operator will be applied to it. `pointer` increment will result in `pointer` point to one past element of array `array` *[which is fine as per language standard]*.

```
 pointer
     |
    _____________________
    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
    ---------------------

after pointer++ :
                        pointer
                         |
    _________________________
    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
    -------------------------
```

So, after incrementing `pointer`, the `for` loop condition `*pointer <= (array + 4)` will result in `false` and loop exits after printing first element of array `array`.

You can access the members of array using pointer `pointer` in this way - `(*pointer)[i]`, where `i` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> member of array `array`.
Below program demonstrate the ways to print the array members:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}, (*pointer)[5] = &array;

    // print array members using pointer 'pointer'
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (*pointer)/sizeof (*pointer)[0]; ++i) {
        printf ("%d ", (*pointer)[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    // using a temporary pointer
    for (int *tmp = *pointer; tmp < (*pointer) + sizeof (*pointer)/sizeof (*pointer)[0]; ++tmp) {
        printf("%d ", *tmp);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    // the above is same as this
    for (int *tmp = array; tmp < array + sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array); ++tmp) {
        printf("%d ", *tmp);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    // another way (check the loop condition)
    for(int *tmp = *pointer; tmp < *(pointer + 1); ++tmp) {
        printf("%d ", *tmp);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

One more thing, when you are compiling your program, the compiler must be throwing warning message

```
warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
```

on `init-clause` and `iteration-expression` of `for` loop:

```
for(*pointer; *pointer <= (array + 4); *pointer++) 
    ^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^
```

the reason is -
`init-clause` expression `*pointer` will result in `int [5]` which will be converted to pointer to first element of array `array` and to which you are doing nothing and
`iteration-expression` is also doing the same because, when unary `*` operator applied to `pointer++` expression result, it will also result in `int [5]` which will be converted to pointer to first element of array `array` and to which you are doing nothing. Hence, they are resulting in warnings.